# How is a non compile time computation function constexpr?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Why is that a non compile time computation function “product”, can be `constexpr`?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

constexpr int product(int x, int y) {
    return x * y;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using namespace std;
    int x1, y1 = 0;
    cout << "input x1:\n";
    cin >> x1;
    cout << "input y1:\n";
    cin >> y1;
    const int a = product(x1, y1);
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `product` function *is* deterministic...

Comment: No, it's effect dependent. similar as get system clock. So it's not deterministic

Comment: Read what it means to be deterministic.

Comment: As you compile this program, Run 2 it times, first: input 4,5, you get 20; Then you run it 2nd time, input 2,2 you get 4. In that sense it's not deterministic, at least it is not a compile time const.

Comment: Your usage of *deterministic* is incorrect here. You mean *only known at run-time*.

Comment: Fun-fact: the word "deterministic" does not appear anywhere in the cppreference.com documentation page for `constexpr`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that `int x1, y1 = 0;` only initializes `y1`. The `x1` variable stays uninitialized. And you don't need to initialize them at definition, as you do it when reading input.

Comment: thanks all I messed, the the whole program is , the function is not. I should’v asked why compile time const & constexpr. And that is the idea come up last night, but missed/messed today. It was, a mistake.

Comment: @Dai Furthermore, determinism is not mentioned in the C++ standard document itself (at least my search didn't come up with anything).

Answer (score 5):

A `constexpr` function like `product` can be called at run-time or at compile-time. This depends on the context in which the function is called.

Calling `product` with run-time values means the function will be treated as a regular run-time function.

Similarly, storing the result of the call in a non `constexpr` variable will also result in the function being called at run-time. (Note that storing the result in a `const int` variable is also considered to be a `constexpr` context.)

To call a `constexpr` function at compile time, it must be called in a context that requires compile time evaluation, with arguments that are known at compile time, and stored in a `constexpr` variable.